# ImportError: cannot import name 'export_tflite_ssd_graph_lib'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Trying to import my train model to `TensorFlow Lite` fails with this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'export_tflite_ssd_graph_lib'
```

What is this happening?

Comment: Welcome. I edited your post and added formatting, changed the wording to better reflect the issue. Concerning the issue your facing, make sure you have configured the PATH properly. read the documentation concerning Object Detection (if your coming from that)

Answer (score 0):

By following this tutorial:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md
I was able to get around this issue.

Make sure you run it from 
/models/research